# Quick navigation (with autocompletion) to an org heading

Tags: org-mode

I have a contacts.org file whose structure looks like this :

```
* Contacts
** John DOE
** Alicia PING
** Bob DELTA
```

I'd like to be able to :

- quickly set up a link to, for instance, Alicia PING, from a different org file;
- quickly navigate to Bob DELTA from anywhere in Emacs.
- in both cases, be able to do this with autocompletion (because I might not remember John's surname...)

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way to do this in the manual, so I programmed a solution in 3 steps:

1. Retrieve the headings of the org file `contacts.org`. Although a very simple requirement, no function seems to do that in the manual, so here's mine:

```lisp
(defun get-headers (org-filename)
  "Get the headers of the org-file located at <org-filename>"
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect org-filename)
    (let ((parsetree (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline))) 
      (org-element-map parsetree 'headline 
                   (lambda (hl) (org-element-property :title hl))))))
```

which you would call, for instance, with `(get-headers "~/contacts.org")` :

`("Contact" "John DOE" "Alicia PING" "Bob DELTA")`.

2. Building from that, here's how to create a quick link to a contact, from an org-file:

```lisp
(defun link-to-contact ()
"Quickly insert a link to one of the contacts in ~/contacts.org, with autocompletion."
  (interactive)
  (let ((contact 
     (completing-read "Link to contact: " (cdr (get-headers "~/contacts.org")))))
    (insert (format "[[file:~/contacts.org::*%s][%s]]" contact contact))))
```

3. And here's how to quickly go there:

```lisp
(defun goto-contact ()
"Quickly navigate to a contact in ~/contacs.org"
  (interactive)
  (let ((contact 
     (completing-read "Go to contact: " (cdr (get-headers "~/contacts.org")))))
    (pop-to-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/contacts.org"))
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (search-forward (format "** %s" contact))))
```